# Getting an Error "moment" is not defined

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Hi I am working on a Lightning application.
I have a parent and a child component.

This is my parent component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="EventController">
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',$Resource.jQuery,$Resource.MomentJs,$Resource.FullCalendarJS)}" 
              styles="{!$Resource.FullCalendarCSS}"
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:attribute name="eventsAttr" type="sObject" default="{}"/>
<div style="width:70%;float:left;">
    <c:CalendarUI events="{!v.eventsAttr}" />
</div>
```

Here is my Parent JS Component:

```
 doInit : function(component,event,helper){
     var fetchList = component.get("c.getEvents"); 
    fetchList.setCallback(this,function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if(state === "SUCCESS"){
            component.set("v.eventsAttr",response.getReturnValue());
        }
    })
    $A.enqueueAction(fetchList);
}
```

And This my Child Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="EventController">
<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:attribute name="events" type="sObject" default="{}"/>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Now my problem is I am getting an Error Message that says

```
"This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: c:CalendarUI$controller$doInit [moment is not defined]
Failing descriptor: {c:CalendarUI$controller$doInit}"
```

And here is my JS Controller for my child Component:

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.fetchRecord(component);
}
})
```

My Helper for my child component:

```
({
fetchRecord : function(component){
    var events = component.get("v.events");
    var getArrList = this.toFullCalendarFormat(events);
    this.dataToCalendar(component,getArrList);
},
toFullCalendarFormat : function(events){
    var i = 0;
    var arr = [];
    var result = events;
    for(i in result){
        arr.push({
            'Id':result[i].Id,
            'start':result[i].StartDateTime,
            'end':result[i].EndDateTime,
            'title':result[i].Subject,
            'ownerId':result[i].OwnerId,
            'ownerName':result[i].Owner.Name,
            'location':result[i].Location,
            'description':result[i].Description
        });
    }
    return arr;
},
dataToCalendar : function(component,data){
    var m = moment();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
        eventClick:function(data){
            component.set("v.events",data);
            component.set("v.dateStart",data.start);
            component.set("v.isOpen",true);
        },
        eventDragStart: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
            console.log(event);
        },
        defaultDate: m.format(),
        editable: true,
        navLinks: true, 
        weekNumbers: true,
        weekNumbersWithinDays: true,
        weekNumberCalculation: 'ISO',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        events:data
    });
}
})
```

Please help on this. I already call my moment.js but then still it has an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load your JavaScript libraries in the CalendarUI component, since that is where you are actually using them. Libraries are not automatically shared between components, even within the same namespace. This is in contrast to classic HTML, where a library is loaded once and available to the entire page.

Your child component will need to remember if the resources have been loaded yet, as well as a change handler on the events attribute. Then, in the afterScriptsLoaded, it would render any events, if available. It would also need to render the calendar again if the libraries are loaded *and* the data changes.